# "How to convert" Plain text algorithm to pseudocode

Tags: java, algorithm, stack, plaintext

here is the Question {https://drive.google.com/open?id=1lQLYfMJ-kw3yCIBa4BCPhZ0X0DIIoRMK}

i want to convert these steps of algorithm into JAVA pseudocode :

First step - pop the top of stack(s) and push it to stack(T)

second step - store the top (s) in the variable (v)

third step - pop all elements in stack(T) and push it again in stack(s)

forth step - push variable (v) element in stack (S)

repeat these steps until reverse the full stack **But repeat the first step by 1 each time you finish these steps and repeat them.**

here is my Stack Diagram solution {https://drive.google.com/open?id=1K5YtZdFl1Bhgz6NhFqOA1Z0CppshaFeW}